# Auto Selecionar o primeiro valor de um Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

***Olá estou usando uma extensão no chrome chamada "tampermonkey" e preciso criar um função que auto selecione o primeiro valor de um Select Option***

```
<select tabindex="-1" class="select-large"><option value="-">[Escolha...]</option> <option value="[object Object]"> NOME </option></select>
```

***No caso irá sempre selecionar o primeiro nome!***

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, não sei se entendi muito bem mas essa tag option tem o parâmetro selected que vc pode marcar pra quem vc quer selecionado.

ex:

```
<select id="meu-select" tabindex="-1" class="select-large">
   <option value="-" selected>[Escolha...]</option>
   <option value="[object Object]"> NOME </option>
</select>
```

Veja a documentação:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

caso queira pode fazer isso no javascript:

```
// se o value do select ficar igual o value de algum dos option ele será o selecionado
document.getElementById('meu-select').value = '-';
```

ou se você não puder dar um ID pro campo pode usar pela classe que ela ja tem:

```
// lembrando que pela classe podem vir multiplos objetos
document.getElementsByClassName('select-large')[0].value = '-';
```

Comment: estou querendo usar o script na página de um game, por isso estou usando a extensão tampermonkey.. Entende?

Comment: tente utilizar esse segundo código, direto no console do navegador na página em questão, em casos como esse é interessante você incluir na pergunta o link pra poder reproduzir o teste.

Comment: Não selecionou nada com este código ... Estou criando um script para o jogo the crims

Comment: vai na pagina em questão e abre o console do navegador, com esse codigo javascript o primeiro select com a classe 'select-large' vai ter selecionado o primeiro registro: document.getElementsByClassName('select-large')[0].selectedIndex=0; 

você pode fazer um for com esse javascript pra setar todos os selects da pagina com essa classe

Answer (score 0):

Teste com o seguinte código, lembrando que é necessário dar um nome aos options ou id.

document.getElementsByName('optionName')[0].selected = true